# Magento 2: create table dependent on configuration

Tags: magento2, install-script, table

I have a requirement where I need to create a custom table in database but these should be dependent on some configuration of module.

Lets say I have enable disable configuration in my module, if any one change configuration value to enables then table will create in database otherwise no creation of table.

**Note:** this configuration is one time only means if any one select Enable then he can not change back to Disable.

Let me know if it is possible in magento, as if we use installer then it will execute once we upgrade the setup or enable the module.

And if yes then is it a correct way to do and also explain the correct way to achieve this requirement.

Comment: in your resource model file you can write a create table query to create table with enable/disable condition.

Comment: @seeni thanks for the reply, I also thought for the same concept but i am looking for any other solution if available.

Comment: if you taking installSchema, once the version number updated in table then your table creation won't considered. So better if we are go with resource model.

Comment: What the problem if table will create always?